# Renaming files using regex?

Tags: regex, linux, bash

I need to rename *-dev.example.com.cfg to *-prod.example.com.cfg

For example, if the filename is db-dev.example.com.cfg I need to rename it db-prod.example.com.cfg

There are like a 200+ files, is there a way to do it via command line ?

Comment: Is there anything you have done to try to solve this problem? We will be more willing to answer your question if you tell us what you have tried so far. (Helpful links for asking better questions: [ask], [help])

Comment: Do you have `rename` installed?

Comment: Seems that you aren't inclined to put in any effort. A simple search would have fetched you multiple solutions.

Comment: @ExplosionPills rename did the trick thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex are not required for this, so since you're on Linux, you can use `rename` from util-linux. On Debian and derivatives like Ubuntu, the command is called `rename.ul`.

```
rename dev.example.com.cfg prod.example.com.cfg *.cfg
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in pure bash with [parameter substitution](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/parameter-substitution.html).

```
for file in *-dev.example.com.cfg; do
  mv "$file" "${file/%-dev.example.com.cfg/-prod.example.com.cfg}"
done
```

Answer (score 0):

zsh has zmv, that might be handy if doing such things regularly http://zshwiki.org/home/builtin/functions/zmv